# Magento 2.3 Custom Order Status Reverts Back to Processing

Tags: orders, magento2.3.3, order-status

I have created an custom order status by following below link.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-status-custom.html

named "**Online Payment Success**" and I set this  status to my order when a Invoice is generated for that order using event named **"sales_order_invoice_pay"** everything seems to work fine in my local setup but when I pushed the code to server the status is set but reverts back to processing

Code in Observer

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class SalesOrderStatus implements ObserverInterface
{   
    /**
    * @param EventObserver $observer
    * @return $this
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    ){
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
            $currentOrder=$observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder();
            $paymentMethod  = $currentOrder->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
            if($paymentMethod=="braintree" || $paymentMethod=="paypal_express")
            {   
                $currentOrder->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
                $currentOrder->setStatus("payment_captured");
                $currentOrder->addStatusToHistory($currentOrder->getStatus(),"Invoice Generated");  
                $currentOrder->save();      
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Add full details please

Comment: @Jai Can u please check the code of my observer i have edited the problem description

Thanks!!